# Deliberately corrupt the search index

Tags: 2013, search, index, index-component

On our SharePoint 2013 on-premise (test farm) I want to deliberately corrupt the search index. This to test backups, fail-over and multiple index components.

Any clues or tips on how to do this? Simply removing some files from the index folder does not work as expected.

Comment: Found a way to corrupt the index. Stop the Search Host Service and then replace one of the files in the index folder by an empty (text) file with the same name and extension.  I always pick a file from the %default folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try couple of things.

- fill the drive space on the your index location.Try to run the indexer
- Fill the disk space on the Index Database Server.
- While index is propagation try to reboot the index server.
- stop the crawler while it is running, do couple of times.